# How did really small municipalities function in The Netherlands in the 19th and 20th century?

Tags: government, netherlands, settlement

I'm always amazed by the small villages in The Netherlands that used to be separate municipalities well into the 20th century.

Take for instance [Ellewoutsdijk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellewoutsdijk). It was an independent municipality until 1970. According to Wikipedia and other sources, in 1840, it had about 100 houses and about 700 inhabitants, so it was never that big. It currently has a few more houses, 150 in total, but fewer inhabitants, 375.

How did such small municipalities function?

With small numbers of inhabitants, were there enough people to fill all municipal jobs, or were jobs "outsourced" to other organisations, be they governmental or not? What responsibilities did the municipality have? Were there any civil servants employed by the municipality?

What was the role of the mayor? Did he (let's face it, most of them were male; the first female mayor in The Netherlands came about in 1946) have enough to do, or was it a part-time job? Were there any aldermen?

Comment: Anthropologists find that [the smaller a social grouping is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribe#Classification), the less stratified it is, and the less specialized people's roles are. One would imagine the principle applies to municipalities as well as states. So I'd expect to see a spectrum, roughly based on how small the town is.

Comment: Even today small towns can have a mayor who is a volunteer doing that part time on top of their regular job. No other municipal jobs exist in such a small town.

Comment: And small Scottish islands with few ferry services/flights have part-time harbourmasters/airport staff.